# How to pass wide strings in Java calling the MessageBoxW function in user32 lib

Tags: java, jna, widestring

I am currently struggling to use the function `MessageBoxW` in Java. I have managed to successfully call the user32 library and use the `MessageBoxA` function. Here's my code below:

```
package messagebox;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class MessageBox 
{
    public interface user32 extends Library
    {
        public int MessageBoxA(int something, String text, String caption, int flags);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Program starting... Library loading... ");
        user32 lib = (user32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", user32.class);
        System.out.println("Presenting Message Box ...");
        lib.MessageBoxA(0,"MessageBox success!!!","Attention",0);
    }
}
```

I've looked around and could not find any conclusive answers but something tells me that I need much more sophisticated coding to tackle this problem. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried doing it? What is the problem that occurred?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jorn. Whne running the code above I get the expected 'Attention' as the Message Box title and 'MessageBox success!!!' as the message box content. When replacing the MessageBoxA function with MessaseBoxW, the message box is successfully created but the characters display in (what I think is) Mandarin.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [documentation](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html#strings) (confirming my suspicions). Java strings, which by default have 16 bit characters, are converted to 8 bit character strings so they fit the C `char*` type.

But what happens if you actually want to print wide (16 bit) characters on the C side? The ascii values that were obtained from converting the java string are interpreted as unicode values, so they don't match what you typed.

The documentation mentions using the `WString` type to avoid the conversion to ascii.

You should change the method signature to:

```
int MessageBoxW(int something, WString text, WString caption, int flags);
```

And then call it with:

```
lib.MessageBoxW(0, new WString("MessageBox success!!!"), new WString("Attention"), 0);
```

---

Tested with jna-4.2.2

Comment: I've imported the com.sun.jna.WString library now and changed the method signature as suggested. However, I get a flag in the(lib.MessageBoxW(0,"MessageBox success!!!","Attention",0);) line of code, as follows: incompatible types: String cannot be converted in to WString. When I run the code, I get the following error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: messageboxw.MessageBoxW.user32.MessageBoxW
 at messageboxw.MessageBoxW.main(MessageBoxW.java:32)
Any ideas?

Comment: @AnaLoureiro You're calling the function incorrectly. Should be: ```lib.MessageBoxW(0, new WString("MessageBox success!!!"), new WString("Attention"), 0);```

Comment: Thank you so much Jorn! Worked like a charm! Guess I still have a long way to go.

Comment: Even better, make use of the `W32Options.UNICODE_OPTIONS`, which automatically maps `MessageBox()` into `MessageBoxW()` and Java `String` into `const wchar_t*`.  See the JNA jna-platform.jar library mappings as an example.