# Call DLL written in Delphi from Java

Tags: java, delphi, dll, jna

I have a simple DLL written in Delphi 10.4. When I call the DLL from another Delphi application, everything works 100%, but when I call the same DLL from a Java application (using JNA) I get strange results.

I initially declared my DLL input parameters of type PChar. When I call the DLL from the Java app, I get funny characters inside my DLL. I changed it to ShortString, but then I loose the first character of the string in my DLL. I probably need to do some datatype casting in Java but I cannot find out what. Can somebody perhaps help?

Here is a sample DLL in Delphi to demonstrate:

```
procedure TestDataTypes(PCharVar: PChar; ShortStringVar: ShortString); stdcall;
begin
  ShowMessage('PChar: ' + PCharVar + #13#10 +
              'ShortString: ' + ShortStringVar);
end;

exports
  TestDataTypes;
```

Code to call DLL from Delphi:

```
procedure TestDataTypes(PCharVar: PChar; ShortStringVar: ShortString); stdcall; external 'TestDataType.dll';
...
TestDataTypes(PChar('PChar Value'), 'ShortString Value');
```

Code to call DLL from Java:

```
INSTANCE.TestDataTypes("Java PChar Value", "Java ShortString Value");
```

Results: Top is when DLL is called from Delphi and bottom when it is called from Java:
[image]

**Some Feedback:**
I changed the datatype in Delphi to PAnsiChar and it works on my local pc. When deployed, it worked on some client machines but not others.
The error I get when I call the DLL from my Java app is "Invalid memory access". I have added logging in my DLL and it seems it does not even enter the DLL....
I have also changed the Java datatype to WString but that did not make a difference.

Delphi code:

```
function HasCOMConnection(COMServerName: PAnsiChar): Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  WriteLog('HasCOMConnection: 64-Bit DLL entered');
  Result := HasConnection(COMServerName);
end;
```

Java Call:

```
    private interface IPMOProcessLabResult extends com.sun.jna.Library {
        boolean HasCOMConnection(String COMServerName);
    }

    private boolean canConnectToCOMServer() {
        try {
            IPMOProcessLabResult lib = (IPMOProcessLabResult) Native.loadLibrary(config.libraryName, IPMOProcessLabResult.class);
            return lib.HasCOMConnection(config.comServerName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            new AppendLog(new Date(), this.getClass() + "\t" + ex.getClass() + "\t" + "Exception while trying to connect to COMServer: " + ex.getMessage(), "debug");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you define `TestDataTypes` in Java? Because a Java String literal is neither `PChar` nor `ShortString`.

Comment: Use a `WString`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002326/how-to-pass-wide-strings-in-java-calling-the-messageboxw-function-in-user32-lib).

Comment: @Olivier, what data type would you use in Delphi to go with the WString?

Comment: @Johan `PChar` (as shown in my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PChar` is only an alias, which was changed to `PWideChar` with Delphi 2009 (let's just say, standard string and character types were changed to `Unicode`)! So every character does now use 2 Bytes.

So in order to make your DLL working as it should, you should change `PChar` to `PAnsiChar`.
Or you have to make some changes to your Java app so it does use some two-byte-character type. But I have no Java experience, so I can't help you with that.

And forget about shortstring, this type is not compatible to other languages!

See [this](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html) site for more references about how to use and not to use DLLs.

Comment: Java strings are 2-byte Unicode (UTF-16), same as Delphi 2009+ strings.

Comment: Don't change `PChar` to `PAnsiChar`. Change the Java code to pass UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

`ShortString` is an old Delphi type that holds an ANSI string and stores the length in the first byte. You shouldn't use it.

`PChar`, in recent versions of Delphi, is an alias for `PWideChar`.

You are using [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) to call native code from Java.

A Java `String` internally uses UTF-16.

JNA uses the following rules:

- A `String` is converted to `PAnsiChar`
- A [`WString`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.6.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/WString.html) is converted to `PWideChar`

So, if you want to pass a Unicode string to the DLL, you should declare the Java method like this:

```java
public void TestString(WString text);
```

And in Delphi:

```delphi
procedure TestString(Text: PChar); stdcall;
begin
    ShowMessage(Text);
end;
```

And call the function like this:

```java
INSTANCE.TestString(new WString("A Unicode string"));
```